# How to "Deep Freeze" only the "Standard User Account" on Windows?

Tags: user-accounts, deep-freeze, standard-user

Well based from the title How to "Deep Freeze" only the "Standard User Account" on Windows? are there ways or other programs that can "Freeze" only the Standard User Account and not the Administrator Account so that any changes made on the Standard User Account will be removed once the PC is restarted?

Comment: You may want to specify which Windows version your question applies to and what you mean by "Deep Freeze" - an app by a third party or a method to you are using to avoid changes to the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Mandatory User Profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895(v=vs.85).aspx):

> A mandatory user profile is a special type of pre-configured roaming
>   user profile that administrators can use to specify settings for
>   users. With mandatory user profiles, a user can modify his or her
>   desktop, but the changes are not saved when the user logs off. The
>   next time the user logs on, the mandatory user profile created by the
>   administrator is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

In my organization we use a similar program called drive vaccine. Now keep in mind we used deep freeze for many years and actually I think both are great programs but I did find I liked that with drive vaccine you can create an exclusion drive, and if you throw your Admin account into that exclusion drive it won't be restored like the other profiles. By not having the profile in the drive it's going to be restored. It's fairly simple to set up and go and if i'm not mistaken the program comes with a trial period so you could give it a chance before you commit to a purchase.